# Rails sort date by upcoming first, then descending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid5

I have a collection of Appointments which have a `start_date` DateTime field.

I need to sort those appointments so I have

- The upcoming appointments first
- Then the "past" appointments, most recent first

Ie suppose I have

*I'm using relative times for the purpose of giving an example, bear in mind in the code I have to compare to Time.now*

```
[ in_two_days, two_days_ago, tomorrow, yesterday]
```

I would like the sort to return

```
[ 
  # First upcoming
  tomorrow, 
  in_two_days,
  # Then most recent first
  yesterday, 
  two_days_ago
]
```

I am using Mongoid, but since there are few items in the arrays, I would accept a solution using array methods and not criteria (although a solution with a mongoid criteria would be better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
upcoming, past = appointments.sort_by(&:start_date).partition{ |a| a.start_date.future? }
sorted = [*upcoming, *past.reverse]
```

Comment: Let me know if I should explain in more detail.

Comment: No this is fine, thanks ! Last comment would be to either change `partition(&:future?)` to `partition { |ap| ap.start_date.future? }`, but what I did for more simplicity, was to also define `future?` in my appointment model, so your answer works.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You are of course right. I will edit the answer accordingly in order for it to match the question.